# Typescript generates invalid triple slash directive

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation

With typescript 3.7.3, when I build my project it generates invalid triple slash directives in my main `index.d.ts`.

this is an extract of my `index.d.ts` :

```
/// <reference path="types/augmentations.d.ts" />
/// <reference types="node" />
/// <reference types="fastify" />
/// <reference types="mongoose" />
/// <reference types="@keplr/backend-types/lib/mongo" />
/// <reference types="node/http" />
/// <reference types="@keplr/backend-types/lib/fastify" />
/// <reference types="fastify-cookie" />
/// <reference types="fastify-multipart" />
import * as email from './helpers/email';
import * as password from './helpers/password';
import * as token from './helpers/token';
export declare const models: {
    ...
};
export declare const plugins: {
    MainPlugin: (instance: import("fastify").FastifyInstance<import("http").Server, import("http").IncomingMessage, import("http").ServerResponse>, options: unknown, callback: (err?: import("fastify").FastifyError | undefined) => void) => void;
    RouteLessPlugin: (instance: import("fastify").FastifyInstance<import("http").Server, import("http").IncomingMessage, import("http").ServerResponse>, options: unknown, callback: (err?: import("fastify").FastifyError | undefined) => void) => void;
};
```

The line `/// <reference types="node/http" />` is invalid and generates errors.

How can I prevent TS to generate triple slash directives for `node/http` ?

I tried with TS 3.6, it's still the same.

Here is my `tsconfig` :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["**/__tests__"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem.

It was a problem due to an augmentation of the node http module in an inner lib.

```
declare module 'http' { 
...
}
```

Dropping this augmentation solved the problem